# Iterate a domain in reverse in Chapel

Tags: arrays, chapel

Chapel has a `reverse()` operator for arrays, but I can't seem to make it work on domains

```
var v = {1..8};

for w in v {
  writeln(w);
}

// poops
for w in reverse(v) {
  writeln(w);
}
```

How do I go backwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by iterating over `v` with a stride of `-1`:

```
for w in v by -1 {
  writeln(w);
}
```

These range operations work on both ranges and domains.
More on that in the [Ranges Primer](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/master/primers/ranges.html#operators).